# Trying to add a delete button in a listViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a delete button in a `ListViewBuilder` and I have gotten the Delete function to work but I can not seem to get the listViewBuilder to refresh to show the user the new list without going to another screen.

ListViewBuilder Widget:

```dart
class LayoutBuilderWidgetDoorsOptions extends StatelessWidget {
  LayoutBuilderWidgetDoorsOptions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  String? dropdownValueObjects;
  String? dropdownValueDoorWidth;
  String? dropdownValueDoorPanelType;
  String? dropdownValueOpLcWidth;
  String? dropdownValueOpLcPanelType;
  String? dropdownValueWalls;
  bool deleted = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                width: 150,
                child: DropdownButton(
                  value: dropdownValueObjects,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                  elevation: 16,
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    if (value == 'Sliding Door') {
                      if (SelectedUpperPanelHt == 'None') {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg:
                                'ERROR: Sliding Door can not have top removed. Please remove Sliding Doors or change Upper Height',
                            webPosition: "center",
                            webBgColor:
                                "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #B90E0A)",
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        throw new FormatException();
                      }
                    }
                    dropdownValueObjects = value!;
                    (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                  },
                  items: Options.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              if (dropdownValueObjects == 'Swing Door' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == 'Sliding Door' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == null)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 150,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    value: dropdownValueDoorPanelType,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    elevation: 16,
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      if (value != 'Select A Value') {
                        dropdownValueDoorPanelType = value!;
                        (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                      } else {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: 'Select A Value is not a valid choice',
                            webPosition: "center",
                            webBgColor:
                                "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #B90E0A)",
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        throw new FormatException();
                      }
                    },
                    items: PanelTypeOptions.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (dropdownValueObjects == 'Swing Door' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == 'Sliding Door' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == null)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 150,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    value: dropdownValueDoorWidth,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    elevation: 16,
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      dropdownValueDoorWidth = value!;
                      (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                    },
                    items: DoorWidthOptions.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (dropdownValueObjects == 'Opening' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == 'Light Curtain')
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 150,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    value: dropdownValueOpLcPanelType,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    elevation: 16,
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      if (value != 'Select A Value') {
                        dropdownValueOpLcPanelType = value!;
                        (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                      } else {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: 'Select A Value is not a valid choice',
                            webPosition: "center",
                            webBgColor:
                                "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #B90E0A)",
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        throw new FormatException();
                      }
                    },
                    items:
                        NAOption.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              if (dropdownValueObjects == 'Opening' ||
                  dropdownValueObjects == 'Light Curtain')
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 150,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    value: dropdownValueOpLcWidth,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    elevation: 16,
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      dropdownValueOpLcWidth = value!;
                      (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                    },
                    items: PanelWidthOptions.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                width: 150,
                child: DropdownButton(
                  value: dropdownValueWalls,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                  elevation: 16,
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    dropdownValueWalls = value!;
                    (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                  },
                  items:
                      ActualWalls.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  onPressed: () {
                    deleted = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i < listDynamicDoorsOptions.length; i++) {
                      if (listDynamicDoorsOptions[i].deleted == true) {
                        listDynamicDoorsOptions.removeAt(i);
                        (context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  label: Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have used the Function: `(context as Element).markNeedsBuild();` to reload the dropdownButtons but this does not need to work in this cause because now the context is deleted. Obviously `SetState((){});` will not work since this has to be a Stateless Widget. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you want is the [Dismissable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) widget

Comment: This still uses a setState which can not be achieved do too these being set as stateless widgets to use the list in later methods

Comment: So what are you using for state management?

Comment: the stepper is used as the state manager the List builder is just used to call the list when a new one needs added to the list. @returnVoid